# Dependencies configuration in gulp-jasmine

Tags: typescript, dependencies, jasmine, gulp, lodash

I have a project with both my source code and Jasmine specs being compiled from Typescript and reloaded "onsave" by gulp working really fine. But the problem comes when trying to add lodash as a dependency. I can't figure out how to do it.

My tests running task **without dependencies** looks like:

```
gulp.task("runSpec", function(){
  return gulp.src("specs/built/**/*js")
    .pipe(replace('/src/', '/built/'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('specs/built'))
    .pipe(jasmine());
})
```

Then, I added lodash to my source code and changed my gulpfile passing the next object as a parameter to the `jasmine()` function:

```
{
  config: {
    spec_files: [
        'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'
    ]
  }
}
```

Also tried the above config object (that I think is more accurate):
`

```
{
  spec_dir: "specs/built",
  spec_files: [
      'appSpec.js'
  ],
  helpers: [
      'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'
  ]
}
```

`

But I can't stop getting a *_ is not defined* error when running the tests.
How should I proceed?

Comment: I have the same issue but with knockout. I'll track this question for an answer.

Comment: Finally, I have decided to add a task to my gulpfile where I just start karma (using html reporter instead of the terminal) with 'karma start'